# Using keyup to remove class from dynamically create buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some buttons that are dynamically created. When they are pressed, the `.disabled` class is added to them and the `text()` is entered into an input field. I want to remove the `disabled` class when the input field is empty. I am checking this on the keyup. I have not been successful in doing this and would like some help.

Here is my jQuery:

Binded event:
`$languageInput.on('keyup', _resetLanguageTags)`

Function:

```
function _resetLanguageTags(){
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            console.log('empty');
            $('button').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('disabled');
            });
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have a `console.log('empty');` to make sure that the input is empty and it is working when the input is, in fact, empty.

Comment: Please make fully a reproducible example.

Comment: This really seems to be a matter of debugging.  Have you tried to put a break point inside the function to ensure $('button') is really what you think it is?  Have you tried adding a break point inside the loop, to see if that's executing?

Comment: You know, if they're dynamically created you're not going to be able to get all the buttons with that event listener. It will only register the ones at the time of the document.ready function, unless you use event delegation, which would look like `$languageInput.on('keyup', '#whateverTheParentElementIs',  _resetLanguageTags)`

Answer (score 0):

I this this example will help using the disabled property :

```
<button disabled>a</button>
```

And remove disabled with:

`$(this).prop('disabled', false);`

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/zzrvcov2/)